# Writing linked list fails due to immutability and mismatched types

Tags: rust

I have trouble implementing a linked list in Rust with the operation `append`.
I chose the `struct` to implement it. For simplicity, I left out the head pointer.

```rust
struct List<T> {
    val: T,
    next: Option<Box<List<T>>>
}
```

Currently I have tried to implement the `append` function like this, which does not compile:

```rust
pub fn append(&mut self, t: T) {
    match self.next.as_ref() {
        Some(n) => n.append(t),
        // compile error here
        None => {
            let end = List {val: t, next: None};
            self.next = Some(Box::new(end));
        }
    }
}
```

The error message goes:

```
cannot borrow `**n` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
```

Why is n here as `**n`? The `n` has the type `&Box<List<T>>`, how should I understand the double dereference symbols `**` here?

I understand that I need a mutable reference to the smart pointer, but changing that line to

```rust
Some(&mut n) => n.append(t),
```

or

```rust
Some(mut n) => n.append(t),
```

does not solve the problem, as the compiler complains about mismatched types.
What should I do here to improve it?

Answer (score 2):

You want `as_mut()` instead of `as_ref()`. Per [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html), `as_ref()`

> Converts from `&Option<T>` to `Option<&T>`

in which the reference inside the Option is non-mutable, but `as_mut()`

> Converts from `&mut Option<T>` to `Option<&mut T>`

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I still have a lot to learn about Rust's references.